# Qwt - how to get the select point index with QwtPlotPicker

Tags: c++, qwt

I plot complex data using QwtPlot, so, I reimplement QwtSeriesData for converting my data into QPointF. The "sample(int)" converts MyObject to QPointf. My QwtSeriesData data manages a

```
myVector=vector<MyObject>;
```

Now, I need to select point drawn into my plot. I try to use QwtPlotPicker but it only returns a QPointF.

How to get the index "idx" of the selected point in order to get `myObject=myVector[idx]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the closestPoint() method in the curve.

```
int QwtPlotCurve::closestPoint  (   const QPoint &      pos,
    double *    dist = NULL 
)
```

It will return the id of the closest point in the curve!

Hope this helps you.